# unregister_sidebar() in stand-alone theme not working

Tags: sidebar, editor, register-sidebar

With [this StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9401123/1743124) I can't make the `unregister_sidebar()` work for me.

#### Scenario

I have developed a theme using a sidebar area, where I've used a Widget. But I don't want the 'Editor' to get access to this Sidebar Widgetized Area in Admin area. So I want to do a tweak in my theme's `functions.php`, where I previously declared `register_sidebar()` somewhere to register the sidebar.

I understood that, setting a less priority will trigger the unregister function more earlier, so I tried with:

```
function site_unregister_sidebar() {

    if ( is_admin() && current_user_can('editor') ) {
        unregister_sidebar( 'my_custom_widget_area' );
    }
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'site_unregister_sidebar', 1);
```

But nothing is happening.

- What actually I'm doing wrong?
- Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you just register the sidebar conditionally. I can't actually see the usefulness to register a sidebar to just deregister it again inside the same theme

Comment: you want to run the unregister *later*, not earlier.

Comment: +1 for @PieterGoosen and to answer your question, you have to use a lower priority than one `register_sidebar` runs, but *lower priority* means *higher number*.

Comment: @G-M: post that as an answer please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Milo and G.M. for pointing to the master key, as G.M. said:

> *you have to use a lower priority than one register_sidebar runs, but
>   lower priority means higher number.*

So the final code that is working:

```
function site_unregister_sidebar() {

    if ( is_admin() && current_user_can('editor') ) {
        unregister_sidebar( 'my_custom_widget_area' );
    }
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'site_unregister_sidebar', 20);
```

Because I set my sidebar with priority of 10 with the **same hook** - `widgets_init`.

```
function theme_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array (
        'name' => 'Custom Widget Area',
        'id' => 'my_custom_widget_area'
    ) );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'theme_widgets_init', 10 );
```